# I want to dynamically query WHERE clause using string builder

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, stringbuilder

I want to dynamically build the `WHERE` clause for my query using string builder.

```
private void btnquery_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder strQuery = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder strWhereClass = new StringBuilder();
    strQuery.Append("SELECT * FROM [dbo].[poi5] ");

    if (namecb.Checked)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nametxt.Text))
        {   MessageBox.Show("Please enter the name!!!");
            nametxt.Focus();
            return;
        } 
        else
        {
            if (strWhereClass.Length == 0)
            { strWhereClass.Append("WHERE [Name_POI] ='" + nametxt.Text + "';");
            } else{ trWhereClass.Append(" AND [Name_POI]] ='" + nametxt.Text + "';");
            }
        }
    }

    if (versioncb.Checked)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(versiontxt.Text))
        {  MessageBox.Show("Please enter the version!!!");
            versiontxt.Focus();
            return;
        }
        else
        { 
            if (strWhereClass.Length == 0) 
            {
                strWhereClass.Append("WHERE [Version] = '" versiontxt.Text + "'");
            } 
            else 
            {
                strWhereClass.Append(" AND [Version] = '" + versiontxt.Text + "'");
            }               
        }
    }

    con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=POIFINALLY;Integrated Security=True;");

    cmd = new SqlCommand(strQuery.ToString() + strWhereClass.ToString(), con);
    con.Open();
    da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
}
```

Comment: i have 3 checkboxes and 3 text boxes and one query button. i have a datagridview attached to display the result.

Comment: when i check Name_POI and INstance_UID and write entries in them to query. , it comes as illegal expression near "Where" .

Comment: firstly post your question with proper syntax!!

Comment: I want to dynamically query based on where clause can any1 guide me

Comment: Is there any ERROR in your code ..?

Comment: @RAMBO: please, make proper text formatting in your question.

Comment: I advise against letting end user enter the where clause naively, you need to do some validation for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: obligatory xkcd link http://xkcd.com/327

Comment: So much wrong with this code. 1) Lack of separation of concern 2) SQL injection 3) Copy Pasta for each where clause 4) config (connection string) in code 5) In-line SQL. Please consider using an ORM with a GUI library vendor. for example DevExpress have a nice grid that binds to EF and filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a stored Procedure that takes the filter query dynamically according to cases

```
    Create procedure GetPoi (@Name nvarchar (100),@Version nvarchar (100))
    as 
    begin
    declare @Command nvarchar(max)
    set @Command = 'select * from tablename where name ='''+@Name+''' and Version='''+@Version+''''
    exec sp_executeSql @Command
    end
```

Also you have to make a test to check if the Parameters provided are empty strings and modify your where clause accordingly.
Check Dynamic SQL for more info

Comment: "I have built a dynamic query now based on where and logical operations"

Comment: Great :) Happy to hear. Mark it as answered then